# Thick Cyan lines on edges on export - import mesh?

Tags: 3d-view, export, import, edges

When i enter Edit mode with my object i have thick cyan lines on every edge. I made my model with blender and the exported it to .obj without saving cause i wanted to import it in another project. Then when i entered edit mode in the project where i imported it there are cyan lines on every edges of the mesh. Here's a print screen of what's happening.

[image]

What are those? And how to get rid of them?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Ok, i tried random Things, and apparently is some "Sharp" stuff. So if you go in CTRL+E and select "Clear Sharp" it should disapear.

Answer (score 4):

Those line represents the "Make sharp", there seems to be a bug that create those make sharp edges when exporting meshes. To remove them go to edit mode, edge selection mode. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all edges. Then Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and select "Clear sharp" from the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. If you set the shading to *smooth* and export the shape you won't notice this. Also, if you import the objects with "smooth groups" unchecked you won't see these cyan lines anymore.